# Nop Commerce 3.XX Multistore hosting with Plesk Panel

Tags: ssl, configuration, app-config, plesk, nopcommerce

I am currently setting up 2 stores using nop commerce 3.20. Currently where are 2 separate stores with different domain in our VPS. These are set up as 2 subscriptions in Pleask panel. Dedicated IP and SSL for each site also set up.

Now, once i move to nop commerce 3.20, i can install nop commerce in our primary store (domain) with SSL.

But how to setup other domain using pleask in same App Pool as per Nop Commerce design?

I know in pleask you can set up Alias for domains. But will this work for domain specific SSL's too?

Any other ways? Or any one hosted similar cases?

update,

Found 90% answer to my question from http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/21356/multi-store-roadmap-lets-discuss-update-done.aspx?p=3#89679

But still dont know how to configure SSL for 2nd Domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself.

But, this solution works on Windows 2012 Server with IIS 8.0 or Above and Pleask control Panel with [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) Support. To read about SNI, just google. We were using Virtual Private Server. So i have had control over every setting in the server.

Follow the steps described [here](http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/21356/multi-store-roadmap-lets-discuss-update-done.aspx?p=3#89679).

But it doesn't mention about Setting up SSL properly. So follow the steps below after completing instructions given in above post.

With IIS 8.0 you can create different bindings for each domain with each domain having its own certificate. You have to use SNI, which means very old browsers (eg. IE6) won't work as they don't support SNI. but that is not a huge concern I think, especially as WinXP is already out of support. Most browsers even on mobile platforms now support SNI.

More info [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-server-name-indication-sni-ssl-scalability) and a great walk through is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2012/09/04/server-name-indication-sni-in-iis-8-windows-server-2012.aspx). Not for the faint-hearted!

I would also advise (if you are on dedicated server) using Central Certificate Store to manage the SSL certs - so much easier once you understand it than the old way!

But note, this WILL not work with [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication#No_support) combination of browser and OS. And also by the way on nop commerce multi-store set up, all of your emails for domain alias works as email alias too.